# Моб не обходит точки пути

Tags: c#, unity3d

Моб (префаб) обходит по точкам пути(префабы). Если точки устанавливаются вручную на сцену, то мобы нормально обходят точки.

Если (префабы) точки пути устанавливаются из кода то моб не идёт по ним.

```
//это внутри GameObjectStartLevel
public static GameObject way_point1;
public static GameObject way_point2;

void Start()
        {

    prefab = Resources.Load("prefabs/way_point");
            way_point1 = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;
            //go_sp.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
            x = 390;
            y = 10;
            z = 256;
            vector3 = new Vector3(x, y, z);
            way_point1.transform.position = vector3;
```

Этот  скрипт вешается на моба.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets.scripts.core.ai
{
public class PathAA : MonoBehaviour
{
    NavMeshAgent agent;

    //CharMove charMove;

    //хранит папку точек
    //public GameObject waypointHolder;
    //занесение точек в лист
    public List<Transform> waypoints = new List<Transform>();
    //the next waypoint should have a longerdistance than the target tolerance
    float targetTolerance = 1;
    public int waypointIndex;
    Vector3 targetPos;
    Animator anim;
    public float waitingTime = 0;
    float patrolTimer;
    ////
    private void Start()
    {


        ////
        //Setup the references
        agent = GetComponentInChildren<NavMeshAgent>();
        //charMove = GetComponent<CharMove>();
        //anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

        //Get all our waypoints
        //здесь GameObjectStartLevel
        waypoints.Add(GameObjectStartLevel.way_point1.transform);
        waypoints.Add(GameObjectStartLevel.way_point2.transform);

    void Update()
    {
        Patrolling();
    }

    /*The patrol function is simple
    we check if we reach one waypoint, we wait a bit, then go to the next one
    */

    void Patrolling() //cостояние патруль
    {
        agent.speed = 10;

        if (waypoints.Count > 0)
        {
            //заменить на коллайдер
            if (agent.remainingDistance < agent.stoppingDistance)
            {
                patrolTimer += Time.deltaTime;

                if (patrolTimer >= waitingTime)
                {
                    if (waypointIndex == waypoints.Count - 1)
                    {
                        waypointIndex = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        waypointIndex++;
                    }
                    patrolTimer = 0;
                }
            }
            MoveTo(waypoints[waypointIndex].position, false, targetPos);
        }
    }



    //Because we are going to use following code a lot, we made it into a function to save time
    void MoveTo(Vector3 destination, bool aim, Vector3 lookPos)
    {
        agent.transform.position = transform.position;

        agent.destination = destination;

        Vector3 velocity = agent.desiredVelocity * 0.5f;

        //charMove.Move(velocity, aim, lookPos);
    }
}
```

Загружается список в Waypoints- elements из кода.

На картинке way_point(clone) не рабочая - из кода.

При замене на way_point моб начинает передвигаться к точке.

Объекты точек пути идентичны. Но отличаются цветом иконки.

Почему такой разный результат?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может потому, что отработка метода Start происходит в начале у `PathAA` а потом `GameObjectStartLevel` .....попробуйте в `GameObjectStartLevel` вместо `Start` использовать `Awake` .... либо вообще сделать геттер пойнтов, а из `PathAA` просто вызвать метод типа `GameObjectStartLevel.GetWayPoints();` ...... ошибки какие-нибудь возникают? При дебаге в `waypoints` что написано? Или дебагом не пользуетесь?))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оказалось всё проще.

Надо добавить

```
way_point1.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

Но если вручную установить точку пути на сцену то добавлять на неё Rigidbody не обязательно.